# gdm Ask for password again while I start it from already logged in tty

Tags: arch-linux, login, gdm

I have an **archlinux 4.4 lts kernel**. For some reason I did not allow **gdm** to start automatically at boot. When I'm logged in `tty` and start the **gdm** with command `systemctl start gdm` the **gdm** starts and the gnome login screen appears while it is pointless to bring the login screen because I start it from the tty already logged in, isn't it! Now the question is, why **gdm** ask for me to login? is it the bug of gdm or simply  default behavior? How can I prevent **gdm** to ask for login? 
* please ignore grammar mistakes.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Start GDM as a service and login to that: that is how it is designed to work...

Comment: @jasonwryan can you explain a bit?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Installation

Answer (score 0):

`gdm` tis the graphical login processor.

If you want a logged-in session run `startx`

gdm asks you to log in because it doesn't know who you are.

Comment: I think I ask about gdm, how to change the gdm behavior?  `startx` is not an option here

Comment: gdm is hard to change, I've tried. the documented auto-login options only partially work.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried!?